# sockjs shows popup to save iframe.json file in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, websocket, spring-websocket, sockjs

I'm using spring-boot WebSocket and SockJsClient for notification.
Once the user logs into the system in IE, the following popup is getting displayed,
[image]

**Following is the UI (ReactJS) code:**

```
<SockJsClient url={"URL"} topics={["topicname"]} onMessage={this.showNotificationCount} ref={(client) => { this.clientRef = client }} options={["xhr-polling"]} />)
```

**Backend code (Java spring-boot):**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer
{
  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config)
  {
     config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/user");
     config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
  }

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry)
  {
      registry.addEndpoint("/notification-websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS().setWebSocketEnabled(false);
  }
}
```

**Content of popup file:**

[image]

Can we disable this popup.?

Comment: Is there any error in console in IE 11? Have you checked in other browsers' network tab to see if there's such a file to be downloaded? I find [a similar thread](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client/issues/388) in github and you can try the solutions in the comments. The issue might be related with CORS and you can check [this source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/3c959d3515ded1d021954b6b4ab1aba4e25077c3/spring-websocket/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/socket/sockjs/support/AbstractSockJsService.java#L603) to see how it comes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @YuZhou, No console error in IE, and no such file is getting downloaded in other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

From [this part](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#websocket-fallback-xhr-vs-iframe) of the official doc, in paragraph 5 of subtitle **4.3.3. IE 8 and 9**, it says:

> The Spring SockJS support also needs to know the location of the SockJS client, because it is loaded from the iframe. By default, the iframe is set to download the SockJS client from a CDN location.

I think that's why you get the download information of iframe.

> It is a good idea to configure this option to use a URL from the same origin as the application.

So you can try to config like the example in the doc:

```
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/portfolio").withSockJS()
            .setClientLibraryUrl("http://localhost:8080/myapp/js/sockjs-client.js");
}
```

Comment: Tried this but no luck.!